# Failed To Create Agent after Build Game - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation, navmesh

My game is running normally in the runtime editor. The problem occurs with the build result. seen in the Output Log that the agent (NavMeshAgent) was not created because it did not close enough to navmesh. whereas in the editor the problem did not arise. Next I attach a screenshot of my output log.

[image: Output Log]
[image: Output Log]

Maybe someone knows why this happens? and what is the solution ??

Comment: How are you placing your agent? is it relative to screen size, etc?

Comment: @BugFinder yes I already did that. I have even tried to move my NPC's position to suit Navmesh. I use this code 'public void IntializeAgent(){
  NavMeshHit closestHit;
  Vector3 posisiAwal = this.transform.position;
  if (NavMesh.SamplePosition (posisiAwal, out closestHit, 10, 1)) {
   this.transform.position = closestHit.position;
  }
 }'

Comment: and. its still error like that.

Comment: perhaps because it already is "somewhere" and has thrown the navmesh error at that point

Comment: whether you use the code or not use it, it's still error. The problem is why the error is only when build, when playing in the editor everything runs smoothly

Comment: because the conditions are different most likely.. such as screen size, screen scaling, timing, semi race condition where once built something happens in a different order..